# Using sound assets in Haxe

Tags: audio, haxe, swfmill

I am having trouble playing sound assets in Haxe. I am able to import mp3s with `swfmill` without error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<movie width="100" height="100">    
    <frame>     
        <library>
            ... other resources ...
            <sound id="Shoot" import="shoot.mp3"/>
        </library>
    </frame>    
</movie>
```

In my `Main.hx`, I created a class called `Shoot` which extends `Movieclip` in the same way I used for my `.png` resources. Then I use this class as follows:

```
var sound:MovieClip = new Shoot();
stage.addChild(sound);
sound.play();
```

But at runtime, when this code is executed, I get the error

```
"Error #2136: The SWF File <project swf> contains invalid data".
```

Any obvious mistakes I'm making in my swf xml file or haxe code? How can I debug this error further?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to play sounds from the library by declaring them as Sounds (instead of MovieClips)

```
class Shoot extends flash.media.Sound {public function new() { super(); }}
```

and you don't need to add them to the stage, just play it:

```
var shoot : flash.media.Sound = new Shoot();
shoot.play();
```